# Android Sqlite query - sum of hours

Tags: android, android-sqlite, hour

Working in Time Entry app. Table has StartDate, enddate and Hour.  So I want to display in Daily, Weekly and monthly basis.

Daily- i can fetch directly using date and then i will sum the hours.
In weekly , Trying to fetch a sum of Working hours between Date range. 
First i query to get the Distinct Date and then sum the hours.

```
String query = "SELECT distinct " + COLUMN_DATE + " from "
            + TIME_ENTRY + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE + " >=\""
            + startDate + "\" AND " + COLUMN_DATE + " <=\"" + endDate
            + "\"";

Cursor cursor = dbSet.rawQuery(query, null);
```

I used Sum(Hours), but it does normal Addition.

```
   String subQuery = "select sum( " + COLUMN_HOURS + " ) from "
    + TIME_ENTRY + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE="\""+cursor.getString(0) +"\"";
```

Problem: Any Function or Any other way to do the Sum of Hours in sqlite query.?

Comment: A good start would be removing all those meaningless **\"**

Comment: Thanks @FrankN.Stein. Starter problem. i will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum hours from whole week why are you fetching hours only for one date ? Is there only one date in whole week ? In my opinion this is your mistake.

As far as I understand your idea `query` variable is a SET of dates so you should subquery using `IN` not `=`

Comment: Actually It can have multiple item in one date.

Comment: @Mahesh yes that is obvious but I think that in one week you can have more than one date ? isn't this true ? if yes why are you comparing only to one date not to a set of  dates ?

Comment: yes, its has multiple dates. first i distinct dates and then i am query the hours for a particular date. I didnt know how to do in single query. So i made 2 query to get it.

Comment: @Mahesh you don't get me. You pick dates in `query`. Thats ok. You receive `List` of dates but in you subquery you're using only ONE date. Don't you see it ? You won't sum it properly because your making query like `SELECT SUM(hour) FROM table WHERE date = '30.08.2015'` So you will receive sum of hours only for one day. To sum hours from whole week you need to subquery using all dates from `query`

Comment: if you understand the scenario or what i am doing wrong. Can you suggest how to do it. I having a Listview which display the Daily hours as item and Total hours in a week at end by added all.

Comment: If you want display daily hours from week then you need to iterate your `query` results and pass it to ListView (you will find in google how to do this), if you want to display a sum of hours in week that either make a query from first day in week to last or sum them in loop that I've mentioned. You have all answers in my post and comments :)

Comment: I got your point, Iterate and displaying i done it.  thanks for it. Actually problem is In a day. Eg: i have a many items 2hrs , 1.35hrs, 3hrs, 1.30hrs as hours in single day. i want to sum this all and display it as" 30/08/2015- 08.05 hours" as single item in ListView. and Another days in a week too. summing is my problem

Comment: @Mahesh in this case the problem is that your saving it as hours, you should save this as minutes. Than you could just sum minutes and divide it by 60. In this case it is much harder because `1.35 + 1.30 = 2.65` but you expect `3h 5 minutes`. You see the problem ? If you save hours you won't be able to sum it. Change it to minutes. If you can't just collect hours (don't sum it in sql) and iterate. Than you split data by `.` and you sum manualy hours and minutes. Minutes when there is more then 60 divide by 60 ;)